# what is wrong with my mysql database in wamp?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have installed  wordpress  successfully in local space,every time i can enter into my wordpress ,no problem happen.Today when i input `127.0.0.1\wordpress` ,i got wrong output

```
Your PHP installation appears to be missing the MySQL extension which is required by WordPress.
```

when i input `http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin/` to enter admin,

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_detect_encoding() in C:\BitNami\wampstack-5.4.24-0\apps\phpmyadmin\htdocs\libraries\php-gettext\gettext.inc on line 177
```

the line 177 contain  `$source_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($text);`

```
function _encode($text) {
    $source_encoding = mb_detect_encoding($text);
    $target_encoding = _get_codeset();
    if ($source_encoding != $target_encoding) {
        return mb_convert_encoding($text, $target_encoding, $source_encoding);
    }
    else {
        return $text;
    }
}
```

How can i fix it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable the `mb_string` extension on WAMP. This is a separate extension and you need to enable it.

Since you are on WAMP. Click the Green color `W` icon on your systems tray and do as shown in the screenshot.

### How to do?

```
Click W Icon -> PHP -> PHP Extensions -> php_mbstring
```

[image]

After that restart your WAMP server for the changes to take effect.